# Error: Android-XML:Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am a beginner in Android and building a `linear layout` and getting an error in the layout XML file like this,

**Error**

```
 Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent
```

Error is shown in this part of the code

```
<WebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/browse"
        />
```

Here is my full code of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/url"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="GO" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:weightSum="8"

        >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Go Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forwardpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Forward Page" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Refreshpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Refresh Page" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearhistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Clear History" />

</LinearLayout>

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/browse"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code and how can I get rid of the error ?

I think this might be a very basic question but I tried and could not figure it out.

Details:

API Level : `API 19: Android 4.2.2`

Comment: in parent linear layout change `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: i will add this as an answer so that other facing same issue can be benefited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is mainly because in the parent *LinearLayout*, you have provide `layout_width` and `layout_height` as `wrap_content`. It should be `match_parent`.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: So changing the layout_width and layout_height to match_parent generates an error  "Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent')."

Answer (score 14):

Contrary to what most answers imply, this is not a bug in Eclipse  resp. Android Studio, but a fair warning. It's produced by a LINT check on your layout.

You can remove the warning and work around the 'subtile bugs' like so:

1. Add `tools:ignore="WebViewLayout"` to your WebView (thanks to @StefanDeitmar) and make the tools namespace known by adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your outmost layout element.
2. In your code, add a WebViewClient to your WebView and implement the `OnPageFinished()` callback to invoke a `requestLayout()` on your wrapping layout element.

```java
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        mSurroundingLayout.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer; this worked for me. I believe the basic issue is that WebView can take a while to lay itself out (and for some pages the height will change often). So this tells the enclosing layouts that they should readjust based on the just-measured height. 

Unless, of course, there are other subtle bugs which I haven't yet noticed...

Answer (score 6):

Actually I think that this is a bug in Eclipse, or the latest version 20 Android SDK.

I have screen designs that are made up of stacked web views because their contents come from different sources. My screen layouts "wrap content" for height so that the user always sees what information is returned from the various sources without vast areas of blank. Its an unusual design, but one that has worked well for 4+ years on many similar applications. Yup, I know that I have to be careful about heights, etc, but I'm happy to take on that responsibility.

Eclipse is essentially creating a "Nanny State" - that's not the way we normally do it so its wrong. Pardon me but I differ in opinion.

The way I got around this was to ***close*** the XML file and completely clean the project. This way Eclipse forgets that it ever "nanny nagged" about this issue and everything is good again.

Comment: Or, you could just add tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" to your WebView and Android Lint would stop nagging you about it.

Comment: I agree that this is likely a bug in Eclipse.  I have an existing webview element that works fine for a couple of releases now.  However, today, if I make a [meaningless] change to that layout Eclipse starts throwing this error.  Making the change to match turtle's recommendation above doesn't work as Eclipse doesn't recognize "match_parent".  I had to close and revert the file to get the errors to go away.

Comment: Also note that I can make the same desired changes in an external editor and Eclipse doesn't mind and will build fine, although "match_parent" still causes the build to fail.

Comment: I upvoted because the fix works, but this isn't a bug. It's a new lint rule.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue before, I had to set the height to 250dp, but I couldn't, so what I did was just wrap it into a FrameLayout and set the custom height to it, you can set the height you want to the wrapper (just not `wrap_content`) and it will work with no problem:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view_tutorial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```