# Android xm error: Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent

Tags: android, xml

Although, this question has already been asked here: [Error: Android-XML:Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709703/error-android-xmlplacing-a-webview-in-a-parent-element-that-uses-a-wrap-cont)  . But it didn't have any satisfactory answer.So I am asking it again.  I have taken a `webview` in my xml width height and width as `match_parent`. But every time I open this page, it shows me error "Placing a `<WebView>` in a parent element that uses a `wrap_content` size can lead to subtle bugs; use `match_parent`".
Here is the code:

```
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/wbvw_questn"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: y cant u use relative layout?

Comment: Obviously I can use relative layout, in fact this problem is also going to sort out once I am cleaning my project. But still I am curious to know, why this error is coming there?

Comment: hey buudy i hav pasted xml code in my workspace but im not gettin any error or warning to webview..

Comment: Hi Gadag, I have this webView in relative layout which has the height as "wrap_content", which  I can not make "fill_parent".  So in that case it is showing that error.

Comment: the link mentioned in your question. has been answered and accepted too.. check it out..

Comment: if that doesnt work...post your xml.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are praising the `WebView` into a `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` or whatever as a parent view, you will need to change the parent view's height to `"match_parent"` to get rid of this error.

For example, change something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />
     ...
</LinearLayout>
```

into:

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     ...
     <WebView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ... />
     ...
</LinearLayout>
```